# How do i subset a zoo object based on values for a particular month

Tags: r, zoo

[My zoo object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbXRG.png)
I Would like to create a subset of values (these are discharge values) containing only December flow values.

Thank you!

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the 'months' from the `index` with `format`, get a logical index by comparing with 'Dec', and use that to subset the `zoo` object.

```
z1[format(index(z1), '%b')=='Dec']
#1938-12-03 1938-12-10 1938-12-17 1938-12-24 1938-12-31 
#    49         50         51         52         53
```

If we convert to `xts` object, `.indexmon` from the `xts` package can be also used.  The `.indexmon` starts from 0, so December is 11.

```
library(xts)
z1[.indexmon(as.xts(z1))==11]
```

Other options from the comments are using `grep` on the `index` to get the numeric index and subset (from @Pierre Lafortune)

```
 z1[grep("-12-",index(z1))]
```

Or with `subset/month` option (from @ G. Grothendieck)

```
 subset(z1, months(time(z1)) == "December")
```

#### data

```
library(zoo)
z1 <- zoo(1:100, order.by = seq(as.Date('1938-01-01'), 
              length.out=100, by = '1 week'))
```

Comment: alternative? `z1[grep("-12-",index(z1))]`

Comment: Thanks guys it solved the problem :)

Comment: Yet another way: `subset(z1, months(time(z1)) == "December")`